# Connect PHP (Google app engine) to SQL Server (Cloud SQL)

Tags: php, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I would like to know if it's possible to connect PHP running on Google App Engine to SQL Server 2017 running on Google cloud SQL(same project)?

As far as I can see there is no extension available for PHP to connect to SQL Server, or maybe, to blame is my lack of experience with GC’s products.

I have done this in the past but with MySQL, and that was really easy but now I seem to be stuck.

Is there a solution to this problem or should I try a workaround using a container?

Thank you!

Comment: *"As far as I can see there is no extension available for PHP to connect to SQL Server"* With respect, how hard did you look? An "I'm feeling lucky" Google of [PHP SQL Server drivers](https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+SQL+Server+drivers) brought me straight to the official drivers. [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu - Google App Engine is a different beast. You cannot use IP based addresses unless Serverless VPC Access is enabled. This question is not so simple.

Comment: @Larnu There are 2 different matters, and I think there is a misunderstanding. To be more clear, there is a list of extensions that are enabled and can be enabled here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime . But my issue with this is that there are no extensions for SQL SERVER provided. I am fully aware about sql server drivers, but  as John Hanley said, GAE is quite different. Will try a few workarounds and will keep this updated, maybe others are searching for a solution also.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine Based on the fact that the SQL Server tab is not available on this page, I would assume this is not yet supported. This is not surprising to me as Windows likes to do what it can to make Azure a necessity to use its products. I would consider using another database like Postgres or MySQL unless there is something particular about SQL Server you need. I'm not too familiar with SQL Server myself for this very reason, I don't ever want to be stuck in a situation where my design decisions are in a sense being made by Microsoft.

Comment: Have you tried connecting through a proxy? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-proxy